# Does the set of 2x2 complex matrices form a field

Tags: matrices

Let $C$ be the set of all the matrices of the form $$ C = \{\begin{pmatrix}
z & -w \\ w 
 & z
\end{pmatrix} \; | \; z,\ w \in \mathbb{C}\}. $$

My question would be if the $C$ forms a field with an addition ($+$) and matrix multiplication ($\times$)? If not, why not?

I went through all of the field axioms and couldn´t find the issue but it doesn´t seem right.

Comment: If you restrict to $z,w\in \mathbb{R}$ then this is a representation of $\mathbb{C}$ so then it's a field

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Well, that includes singular matrices like {{1, -i},{i, 1}}, so it won't satisfy the requirement that every non-zero element have a multiplicative inverse.

Comment: It may also be of interest that if you replace one of the columns in your definition with its complex conjugate, you *will* get something where every non-zero element has a multiplicative inverse - in fact, you get a representation of the quaternions.  But it's still not a field, because quaternion multiplication isn't commutative.